# App for creating installers with prerequisites

Tags: gratis, software-development

I am trying to create an installer for the application I developed. 
I am looking for a freeware (or open-source) software to help me create the installer.
The features that are required from the software are:

1. Freeware or open source
2. GUI editor (for example InnoSetup that you can only edit it with scripts is not an option)
3. Support for many files
4. No appearance of the software on my created installer (For example clickteam shows an advertisement of their installer creator software at the end of the installation, so it's not an option)
5. Support for installing prerequisites (for example I need it to install .net framework 4.0, ODBC and some other stuff before installing my application). I will provide the installers for the prerequisites myself inside the installer.
6. Ability to load company data in the created installer (company logos, software logos, company name, software name etc etc)
7. Creating Windows applications (I used C# for development)

Comment: Script-based installers (like [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download)) are much more powerful than GUI-editors. Is there a reason that you want to avoid them?

Comment: Simplicity, easy of use and well GUI editors are easier and faster to learn than script-based installer software

Comment: True, but I think it's worth spending the time to learn a good scripting language in the long run, especially if you plan to do this more than once. The end result will also look better, so it'll pay off. You'll have installers that look like the ones used by Adobe, Dropbox, Mozilla, [and others](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Users)

Comment: Well yes, I do not disagree but I need something fast for now as this is an urgent matter... That's my problem, not the need to learn but the time it takes to learn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always consider looking into using Innosetup +  [Kymoto Inno Script Studio](https://www.kymoto.org/products/inno-script-studio/) - it gives you a GUI front end for creating the setup scripts.  You still get to see and if necessary edit the script but a lot of the work is done for you - especially for "simple" installs.

1. Freeware or open source *From the web site **Inno Script Studio may be used free of charge**, but donations are "appreciated"*
2. GUI editor (for example InnoSetup that you can only edit it with scripts is not an option) ***Mixed - GUI lets you create the base script***
3. Support for many files ***yes***
4. No appearance of the software on my created installer ***The final installer is Inno Setup based***
5. Support for installing prerequisites ***Yes***
6. Ability to load company data in the created installer ***Yes***
7. Creating Windows applications  ***Yes***

[image: New Project Dialog 4]
[image: Screen Shot 2]

Comment: Unfortunately script editing is to be avoided completely at this phase as we need to ship something fast and scripting has a learning curve which we do not have time for now

Comment: If your app is written in Visual Studio there is an Inno Setup extension that allows you to write the setup directly in IDE without any editor.